# Understanding Lucene Syntax

Tags: lucene

Does this ...

```
+(content:#b content:#a +content:#c)
```

mean ...

```
where content includes #b AND #a OR content includes #c?
```

I read through [Query Parsing Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Grouping), but still wasn't sure about the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not what it means.  Firstly, the outer + is implied.  Results won't be returned that match nothing.  So, without any other terms present, that query is identical to

```
content:#b content:#a +content:#c
```

Or: Must match content:#c, and optionally content:#b and/or content:#a

The equivalent for meaning you provided would be:

```
(+content:#a +content:#b) content:#c
```

Comment: You did not include "OR" or || since no operator defaults to "OR." Is that right?

Comment: Yes, sort of. `content:#a content:#b` and `content:#a OR content:#b` are identical. Similarly, `+content:#a +content:#b` and `content:#a AND content:#b` are identical. However, note that there isn't really a precise, equivalent to `+content:#a content:#b` (well, just simply `content:#a` gets the same results, but loses the optional search field, and thus the scoring impact from it).